# WSO2 IS - Using IS as a krb5-admin-server

Tags: wso2, config, kerberos, wso2-identity-server

I have a ***krb5-sftpd server*** on a machine and I want to use the Identity Server as the KDC and the administrative server of the keys.

By now, I can retrieve a ticket from the Identity Server, the thing now is to use the `kadmin - ktadd`  command to pass the keys to the ***krb5-sftpd server***.

I am using Identity Server 3.2.3.

Can I use the command `kadmin - ktadd` on the ***Identity Server***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server 3.5.0 seems to have some issues (https://wso2.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/IDENTITY-922/IDENTITY-922.html) regarding Kerberos Authentication. They have been fixed on WSO2 IS 4.5.0. If you do not specifially require the use of version 3.5.0 please use 4.5.0 to setup the KDC.

The setup process is the same as for 3.5.0. I was able to follow this document:
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/

and get a KDC up and running and use **kinit** and **klist** commands to on it.

If you are trying to use **kadmin ktadd** to add service principal to WSO2 IS, I am not sure if that is possible. The recommended way is to use the WSO2 Management console to add a service principal to the KDC.

Once that is done, you can configure the service (krb5-sftp) to use the KDC.

Comment: The only problem that I actually see is that I can't use the ´kadmin-ktadd´ command on the ftp server to retrieve the keys from the kdc. When I tried several times, the kdc looked up for the user amilaj/admin@WSO2.ORG , user which I can't add to the Identity Server.